# Unable to Parse AVRO using Kafka Input and Avro Codec in Logstash

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to parse avro locally instead of using schema registry url using avro-codec

Here is the input to Kafka:

```
{
  "id": 5839355690199358000,
  "name": "VOH*a|[RF6y?"
}
```

Logstash Output:

```
"@timestamp" => 2022-10-08T14:16:12.907374Z,
         "event" => {
        "original" => "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002������ǉ�\u0001\u0018VOH*a|[RF6y?"
    },
      "@version" => "1",
      "document" => {
          "id" => 0,
        "name" => ""
    }
}
```

Logstash Conf:

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    topics => ["avro-schema-codec"]
    codec => avro {
        schema_uri => "/Users/Smit/Desktop/logstash-8.4.3/config/avro_schema.avsc"
        target => "[document]"

    }
  }
}

filter { }

output {
   stdout {  }
}
```

AVSC file:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "MyRecord",
    "namespace": "com.mycompany",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "long"
        },
        {
            "name": "name",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

PS: I have already tried adding different deserialsers, but it is not working and also have seen other solutions around too.

I have also asked the same in https://discuss.elastic.co/t/unable-to-parse-avro-using-kafka-input-and-avro-codec/316133/1

Comment: Please share your kafka producer code. If it's using the Schema Registry, then Logstash must as well since the bytes are written a special way within Kafka

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am using the Platform called Conduckor, however I can confirm that Schema Registry is working fine, since when i use Schema Registry URL, it works fine in logstash. However for my other use-case, I am planning on using codec-avro

Comment: You cant use a file. You need to use a codec that supports the registry, such as https://github.com/revpoint/logstash-codec-avro_schema_registry

Comment: Perfect, I hope this is integrated in Logstash Bundle officially.

Comment: I'm not sure it is. Needs to be installed separately